# Error Handling on yEnc in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, error-handling

I am using the yEnc module with Node.
I have been trying to work out how to carry out error handling as the module has no token for an err.  How would I perform error handling?

The code I have is as follows:

```
exports.emailSNSclient = SNSClient(function(err, message) {
    var payload = JSON.parse(yEnc.decode(message.Message));
    logger.info(payload);
```

I am unsure if try catch would work because I have been led to believe it doesn't work too well with node.

What is the correct way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try/catch works fine in this case, as yEnc.decode() is a synchronous operation. The only time try/catch is not suitable is when attempting to catch errors from asynchronous operations.

The following will work fine:

```
exports.emailSNSclient = SNSClient(function(err, message) {
  try {
    var payload = JSON.parse(yEnc.decode(message.Message));
    logger.info(payload);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)  
  }
}
```